# What is the longest time that a mammal has spent in microgravity?

Tags: iss, microgravity, animals, mir

The ISS has had crew since the year 2000. Do the health issues with microgravity keep compounding, or do they stabilize after a few years and maybe even diminish? I suppose the animal needs to be a mammal, fairly big and long lived.

Comment: Technically,  Polyakov is a mammal.

Comment: The longest time non-humans have spent in space is only 91 days. They were mice who lived in the mice drawer system on the ISS in 2012. See this  [NASA report](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/665.html) on the results of the experiment.

Comment: do you think the posted answer is correct?

Answer (score 14):

437 days in a single stretch.

The mammal was a relatively standard specimen of Homo sapiens sapiens. Known affectionately as [Valeri Polyakov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeri_Polyakov) by his handlers, the subject was launched to orbit on-board [Soyuz TM-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TM-6) on August 29, 1988.

The mammalian subject was allowed free movement in a spacious [350 cubic meter enclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir), provided with a diet consisting of around 100 g of protein, 130 g of fat and 330 g of carbohydrates per day <sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir#Food_and_drink)</sup>, and allowed several [trips outside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_EO-3#Spacewalks) during the course of his mission. 
The subject was returned to Earth on-board [Soyuz TM-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TM-7) on April 27, 1989.

The record for the longest *total* time any mammal has spent in microgravity is also held by a specimen of Homo sapiens sapiens; [Sergei Krikalev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Krikalev), with 803 days in space.

As to the second part of your question:

> Do the health issues with microgravity keep compounding, or do they
>   stabilize after a few years and maybe even diminish?

We simply don't know. Even Polyakov's record holding flight didn't break the 18 month mark. The ongoing [One Year Mission](https://www.nasa.gov/content/one-year-mission/) is a start towards the kind of long duration experiments that will eventually answer your question.